# How are categorical features encoded in lightGBM?

Tags: python, machine-learning, encoding, decision-tree, lightgbm

LightGBM has support for categorical variables. I would like to know how it encodes them. It doesn't seem to be one hot encode since the algorithm is pretty fast (I tried with data that took a lot of time to one hot encode).

Comment: See this comment and the referenced issue: https://github.com/Microsoft/LightGBM/issues/254#issuecomment-318811572

Comment: An update resource, for anyone interested in how lightgbm handles categorical features: **Categorical feature support:** https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Advanced-Topics.html#categorical-feature-support **Optimal split algorithm for categorical features:** https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Features.html#optimal-split-for-categorical-features

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/Microsoft/LightGBM/issues/699#issue-243313657

> The basic idea is sorting the histogram according to it's accumulate values (sum_gradient / sum_hessian), then find the best split on the sorted histogram, just like the numerical features.